# Reset admin password on Fortinet FortiWiFi 60D

Tags: router, wireless, fortinet

I've tried to log in to this device by doing the following.

1. Default credentials

   ```
   username: admin
   password: <none>
   ```
2. Maintainer credentials in the FortiExplorer console interface.

   ```
   username: maintainer
   password: bcpb + serial number
   ```
3. Holding the reset button for varying lengths of time, and during boot.
4. Installing a newer firmware from ftp://pftpintl:F0rt1intl@support.fortinet.com

I've gleaned this information from random blogs. I can't find an actual manual, just spec sheets and sales pamphlets.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Reset Button: When enabled (default state), resets the unit to its factory default settings **if pressed during the first 30 seconds after a reboot** -- [Fortinet KB](http://kb.fortinet.com/kb/microsites/search.do?cmd=displayKC&docType=kc&externalId=FD33883&sliceId=1&docTypeID=DT_KCARTICLE_1_1&dialogID=56637278&stateId=0%200%2056639128)

[Resetting a lost admin password - PDF](http://docs-legacy.fortinet.com/fgt/sysadmin/Resetting_a_lost_admin_password.pdf)

Comment: This worked. Not enough points to upvote.

Answer (score 1):

Methods above did not work for me.

Just had success with

1. cycle power
2. press and continue to hold reset button, through boot

   - Status blinks fast
   - flashes through eth lights
   - Status blink slow
   - Status blinks very fast.
3. release button, unit reboots.
4. Able to login with defaults.

Answer (score 0):

Here are the exact steps that Nick took:

1) Install FortiExplorer. Connect the usb cable to the router and go to the web view. First just try ‘admin’ and no password. If that fails, you’ve gotta reset it.

3) Download a firmware from the Fortinet ftp server: ftp://pftpintl:F0rt1intl@support.fortinet.com

4) Upload the firmware to the router.

5) Unplug the power. Plug it back in and wait for the router to boot up.

6) Use a pen to hold the reset button for about 5 seconds within 30 seconds of the router booting up.

7) At this point I was unable to access the web view. Maybe try rebooting again and see if it works. If it does, you’re done.

8) Install the new firmware that you uploaded in step 4. Reboot and login with ‘admin’ and no password.

I took those exact steps and it worked on one of our FortiGate 60Ds. Just hitting the reset button for 5 seconds did not work.

Comment: Apparently, Nick used better formatting. And as the question was already answered, what does this add?

Answer (score 0):

To do the manual reset you must wait for the Fortigate unit STATUS light to turn GREEN before pushing the reset button.

Answer (score 0):

@Brodric’s answer helped me figure out the solution, I finally got my Fortigate 60D properly reset, but for me the process was a bit different.
After power cycling the device, I waited about a minute until the status light started blinking.
The blinking only lasts about 10 seconds and I had to press the reset button within that time period. Once the status light stops blinking it is too late.

When I pressed the reset button, the blinking light began blinking faster, and then went off. I kept pressing the reset button for an additional 20 seconds just to be on the safe side.
Then I released the press, waited for the device to finish booting and everything worked like a charm.